# Cannot access array values returned by php function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have both *PHP* and *HTML* in one file, following the pattern:

> -HTML1
>   -PHP1
>   -HTML2
>   <-script>
>   -PHP2
>   <-/script>
>   -rest of HTML

In the *PHP2* section, I call a function in *PHP1* which returns an array. 
I can get a value for `count($arr)`, but I cannot print the values in the array. It simply shows as an empty string when I examine the source code in the browser.

When I copy the statements in the function from *PHP1* to *PHP2*, everything works - I can print the values of the array.

Code follows:

```
<?
include('pathdata.php');
function getThePath($node1, $node2){ //pass strings

    $n1 = $matchIDtoNum[$node1]; //get int (from pathdata)
    $n2 = $matchIDtoNum[$node2];

    $res = array();
    $res[0] = $n1;
    $res[1] = $n2;

    return $res;

}


$node1='';
$node2='';
if($_GET["node1"]){
    $node1 = $_GET["node1"];
}

if($_GET["node2"]){
    $node2 = $_GET["node2"];
}

if ($node1!='' && $node2!=''){
$arr = getThePath($node1,$node2);
}


?>

<html>
<head><title>Paths</title>    
<script>

function init(){

<?    
echo ("document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML = 'test';\n");
if($node1!='' && $node2!=''){

    //$n1 = $matchIDtoNum[$node1];
    //$n2 = $matchIDtoNum[$node2];      
    //$res = array();
    //$res[0] = $n1;
    //$res[1] = $n2;    
    //$arr=$res;

    $num = count($arr);
    $str = implode(' ', $arr); 

    echo ("document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML = '$arr[0]';\n"); //Empty string
    echo ("document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML = '$str';\n"); //String with one space character
    echo ("document.getElementById('msg3').innerHTML = '$num'+' '+'$node1'+' '+'$node2';\n"); //this always works
}

?>

}

</script>


</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h1>Given two Nodes, return Shortest Path</h1>
<form name="inputform" action="getpath.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="node1" /> 
<input type="text" name="node2" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
<br/>
<p id ="msg1"></p>
<p id ="msg2"></p>
<p id ="msg3"></p>
<br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice on where I might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Edited to Add: What worked for me was putting global `$matchIDtoNum;` inside the function. i.e.

```
function getThePath($node1,$node2){
    global $matchIDtoNum; 
    $n1 = $matchIDtoNum[$nd1];
    //etc
}
```

This gave the expected output for me.

Thanks to all the commenters and answerers!

Comment: See here, by commenting out the `$matchIDtoNum` Your functon works correctly. [http://codepad.org/ZcbXMDyd](http://codepad.org/ZcbXMDyd) What is the purpose of `$matchIDtoNum[]`?

Comment: $matchIDtoNum is not declared and not global value in getThePath function. where are the values of $matchIDtoNum?

Comment: $matchIDtoNum is an array in the included file pathdata.php. After your comment Davinder, I assigned $n1 and $n2 to randome numbers and it worked fine. So it seems I have an issue with setting this array in pathdata.php to be globally accessible in this php file. I will try changing this to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm.. on this line:

```
$n1 = $matchIDtoNum[$node1]; //get int (from pathdata)
```

It seems you want to get an array value from **$matchIDtoNum**. You can not take a array value from outside of a function, unless you call it as a function. For example like this:

```
$n1 = getMatchIDtoNum($node1); // get int (from pathdata)
```

and on file **pathdata.php** there a line like this:

```
function getMatchIDtoNum($arg){
      // Your code here
      return $matchIDtoNum[$arg];
}
```

Comment: Hmm.... this is interesting to me. :) Instead of using this function (which I shall attempt shortly) is there anyway of making the array $matchIDtoNum to be global somehow, so the funtion in the other file could access it?

Comment: add this line `global $matchIDtoNum;` before `$n1 = $matchIDtoNum[$node1];`

Comment: Thanks... tried it just before I saw your comment. By the way, being fairly new to stackoverflow i had a question. Is there anyway to 'kudo' people who comment and contribute to my solution? I figure picking a person's answer gives them a higher reputation, but what about the others?

Comment: @ValerieParker: What is 'kudo'? About reputation you can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 0):

use the $node1 and $node2 as global variables. like

```
function getThePath(){ //don't pass strings 
    global $node1, $node2;
    .....
}

//call function as
$arr = getThePath();
```

Now you will get your array